# titanium setup JDK not found

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I am newbie to titanium appcelerator. I installed titanium studio 3.2.1. And have installed jdk1.6.0_45. I can't run titanium terminal. It gives following error/
"*This Terminal Emulator is not functional because no 'bash' shell could be found.
Please correct the problem and restart the IDE.*"
So, I use nodejs command window to check titanium setup. I am trying to setup titanium settings with "ti setup" command.
When I check environment, it displays all the configuration settings including, android sdk, android ndk and java development kit. 
Here, i am getting error with java as "JDK not found". I have added environments variables fine. but, still getting error. please help

Answer (score 0):

Titanium Studio has been discontinued almost a year ago. Currently you need to download Appcelerator Studio which you can get from [Appcelerator Platform](http://platform.appcelerator.com).

Appcelerator Studio requires you to have an Appcelerator Platform Account for which you sign up for free at http://www.appcelerator.com/signup